# How to search best match for the string EF4.1?

Tags: entity-framework, lambda

I have an Entity for "Company". When user enters a Company name I have to search my DB whether it is already exists. I can't search by Company name since second time user might be entering the name bit differently or with spelling mistakes. Even in that case I want to find the best match.

Comment: So you always want to scan the entire Company table and try to find a best match based on an algorithm that you have defined?

Comment: Yes. I want to search entire company table to find best match for the company name. I don't have an algorithm yet.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be possible generally.
Look at this tow sample :

"Company Name"
"Company  Name"

you can not determine witch one your users entered.You can just do somethings like these:

- Trim the spaced from begin and the end of entered company name and then save it to db
- Do not allow users to enter some chars like ' "" / \ in the name of company
- replace \t \n or more than one space chars exactly beside each other with one space char

after these such action , you can be hopeful that you can search it by some methods like `String.Contains` (this is not exact)

In other hand , you can have a regular expression that force the user to enter a name that match with that expression ,after this depend on your expression you can search the name exactly (Note not all expression can help you to make it possible)

Good luck
Ali Foroughi

Answer (score 1):

That is mostly impossible. Even with some more advanced tool with ability to correct common spelling mistakes it will not work because these tools are targeted for specific language and its vocabulary (lexical analysis) - company names can consist from non-vocabulary (non-existing) words and foreign words so the tool for correcting spelling errors will either skip them or even make them worse by introducing incorrect spelling (just use MS Word grammar correction set to English and type text in you local language).

Another problem is how to make such spelling correction work in a database. Spelling correction would definitely not be part of common query algorithm. It can be part of full text search but I'm not sure if SQL Server provides this feature out-of-the box ([this MS Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/287145/full-text-search-spelling-correction-capability) says it doesn't).

User must know at least part of the company name - after that you can use approach described by @Ali. Spelling mistakes are his fault. You can make the search process more user friendly for example with features like auto complete offering company names containing currently typed string.